# Show button if class exist on the page

Tags: jquery

I want to create a print button for a specific element with specific class (div.classname) in page, but I want this button to be hidden if this class doesn't exist.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#printButton").click(function(){
        $(".print").printMe();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('div#print').length != 0) {
        printPage('<small class="fontSize16" id="printButton"><a><i class="fa fa-print"></i> print</a></small>');
    } else {
        printPage('');
    }
});

function printPage(s) {
    $('h1').append(s)
}
```

Comment: You need to add your (minimal) relevant code (HTML, CSS, jQuery) to your question, otherwise this becomes a "what jQuery method(s) exist to (theoretically) do stuff?" question. Which, despite my answer, is of little use to anyone in future.

Comment: Please, for the sake of people being able to read, and make sense of, your code: use the '[edit]' link below your question, and add your jQuery to the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's relatively easy, just use `toggle()` with a Boolean switch to show (`true`)/hide (`false`) the `<button>`:

```
$('#buttonElementID').toggle($('.elementClassName').length);
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to give implementation examples due to the absence of any relevant code, context or information in your question. Should you update to offer information, I'll do my best to make my answer more specifically useful.

References:

- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 0):

Look for `.hasClass()` jquery api

Answer (score 0):

First check to see if the class exists using .hasClass, Then you can use .hide and .show depends on whether the class exists or not.
.hasClass [Link](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)
.hide[Link](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` or `.hasClass()` method to check whather the class is available or not.